# Compare data of the same table

Tags: plsql

I need to compare data of the same table who do this.

At example, compare A,10 with B,10 when 10 is a repeat value.

Comment: Are you trying to find **duplicates**?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the cross-product operator, in SQL this would be done as

```
SELECT T1.colA, T2.colA, (T1.colA < T2.colA) as colA_comp
FROM TableName T1, TableName T2
WHERE T1.colB = T2.colB
```

What this does is take the cross-product of the table `TableName` with itself (renamed as T1 and T2), and the `WHERE` clause filters out those records that agree on `colB` (the repeated value 10, in your example).

Answer (score 1):

If you compare with the same table then you may use left Join

```
SELECT t1.cola,t1.colb,t2.cola,... 
from tableA t1
LEFT JOIN tableA t2 on t2.cola = t1.cola
WHERE t1.cola = 10
```

I hope it might be work!